# Cannot compile C++ program with custom header files in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I'm new to C++ and I'm having some trouble trying to compile my program. I have a `Driver.cpp` file which contains `main()`, and 2 header files each with corresponding `.cpp` files. They are all in the same directory. The `Driver.cpp` file only calls a function in one of the other header files, which does the rest of the work. My problem is I cannot compile the code as I keep getting "Undefined symbol first referenced in file" errors. I've tried many different ways of writing the compile code but none works. Here is one I tried:

```
"g++ -lm -o outputfile headerOne.cpp headerTwo.cpp Driver.cpp"
```

If anyone can help me out I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Edit: By the way, I tried this code in Visual Studio before I put it into Linux and it worked. Not sure if that means anything, but thought I'd add that in here. Let me know if I need to attach some code.

Comment: Can you post some code? Maybe the header and implementation files if they are not too large... What is the exact error message? Where is this function supposed to be implemented?

Comment: Usually, "Undefined symbol" means the compiler could not find the definition.  This would mean that some header file is not being included or the definition is skipped due to conditional compilation.

Comment: You will have to post more or most of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Turns out I didn't have some variables defined in my .cpp files as "extern" in my .h files and I was missing "inline" in my function definitions. Thanks anyway for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since your code works in visual studios I am going to assume your includes are proper read this link it might give you some guidance for linux environment

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html